# How to randomly render credit card number values with Python scripts

Tags: python

Modeling a bank card with Blender, but I don't know how to use a Python script to randomly update bank card values。

Comment: Use Animation Node plugin and build a node network that generates a random number from frame number input. Feed that into Text object. Render the animation, each frame will have a random number.

Comment: Can give me a Python programming instance from the Text object.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) solution:

[image]

Which produces:

[image]

It works by taking a frame number and using it as a seed to generate 4 random strings of 0-9 characters. Each node has also its own seed, they should differ, so you get 4 different numbers from a single frame number.

[image]

Last step is to join the strings together into single one with a space separator in between:

[image]

---

To fool the average viewer the solution above is enough but to be correct more math should be involved which is not hard but would clutter the example. Not every made up credit card number is valid. Each CC company has some rules the numbers should obey and they also differ in length:

[Payment card numbers (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number)

The last digit is also usually a checksum number that can be calculated using [Luhn algorithm (Mod 10)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

A starting point to get a list of random digits that you can do math on and then convert it to text could look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you had a text object named 'Text' (`bpy.data.objects['Text']`) and wanted to generate a random credit card number every 5 frames and write it to the text object(`bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body`). You could use an [Application Handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html) for this.

```
import bpy
from random import randint #We need something to generate random numbers with

def random_numbers(scene):
    card_number='' 
    #card number reset to empty string

    if (scene.frame_current%5==0): 
    #every 5th frame could be every frame number that has no reminder after dividing by 5

        for group_of_4 in range(0,4):
        #we need to do it 4 times so let's use a loop instead of typing

            card_number += str(randint(0,9999)).zfill(4) + ' ' 
            #zfill is for leading zeros

        bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body = card_number
        #let's write the text to the text object

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(random_numbers)
#and let's add the actual handler that will run before every frame change
```

If it bothered you that the numbers change every time you scroll through the timeline you could use the frame number as the seed for random function(as in Jaroslav's great answer) with the handler as well:

```
import bpy
from random import random, seed

def random_numbers(scene):
    card_number=''
    if (scene.frame_current%5==0):
        seed(scene.frame_current)
        i = random()
        for group_of_4 in range(0,4):
            card_number += str(int(i*10000)).zfill(4) + ' ' 
            i = i*10000 - int(i*10000)
        bpy.data.objects['Text'].data.body = card_number

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(random_numbers)
```